# jQuery click event not working on iPhone browsers (Already tried cursor:pointer;)

Tags: jquery, ios, css, click

I want to set a click event on anchor tags in my wordpress site. I was able to get it to work on all of my devices (PC, Android phone, tablet) except for my iPhone.

I have tried setting the 'Cursor' to 'Pointer' for the anchor tags to no avail.

I have tried everything I could find on SO and nothing seems to work :/

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$("a[href^=#]").on('click touchstart', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); var dest = $(this).attr('href');
      console.log(dest);
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(dest).offset().top }, 'slow');
    });
```

```css
.scroller {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#res-mobile" class="scroller" onclick="void(0)">
  <div id="mobile-hero-book" class="book-now-btn">Book a Car</div>
</a>
```

Comment: onclick attribute is not needed in the anchor tag because you have add handler by jQuery

Answer (score 0):

So If I understood it you instead of using `href` you can try using `onclick` to use a function in `JS` like this:

```js
function ANYTHING() {
   $("a[href^=#]").on('click touchstart', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); var dest = $(this).attr('href');  
   console.log(dest);
   $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(dest).offset().top }, 'slow');
  });
}
```

```css
.scroller {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<a class="scroller" onclick="void(0)" onclick='ANYTHING('>
   <div id="mobile-hero-book" class="book-now-btn">Book a Car</div>
</a>
```

Please let me know if that helped! You can still keep the `href` in the `html` if you need it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this little jQuery plugin i wrote for just the problem you are experiencing:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#stupid-button").touch(function() {
    console.log("The stupid button was pressed!");
  });
});

$.fn.touch = function(callback) {
  var touch = false;
  $(this).on("click", function(e) {
    if (!touch) {
      console.log("Click detected!");
      let callbackReal = callback.bind(this);
      callbackReal(this, e);
    } else {
      touch = true;
    }
    touch = false;
  });
  $(this).on("touchstart", function(e) {
    $(this).blur();
    if (typeof e.touches != typeof undefined) {
      e.preventDefault();
      touch = true;
      console.log("Touch detected!");
      let callbackReal = callback.bind(this);
      callbackReal(this, e);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="stupid-button">Click Me</button>
```

EDIT 1:

Deleted

EDIT 2:

I misunderstood the question. The above code is still useful with iOS devices, but here's what you should do to handle the anchor tags. Get rid of the #id href:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".anchor").touch(function() {
    var targ = $("#" + $(this).data('targ'));
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: targ.offset().top
    }, 'slow');
  });
});

$.fn.touch = function(callback) {
  var touch = false;
  $(this).on("click", function(e) {
    if (!touch) {
      console.log("Click detected!");
      let callbackReal = callback.bind(this);
      callbackReal(this, e);
    } else {
      touch = true;
    }
    touch = false;
  });
  $(this).on("touchstart", function(e) {
    $(this).blur();
    if (typeof e.touches != typeof undefined) {
      e.preventDefault();
      touch = true;
      console.log("Touch detected!");
      let callbackReal = callback.bind(this);
      callbackReal(this, e);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#target-ele {
  margin-top: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anchor" id="link-1" data-targ="target-ele">Click Me</a>

<div id="target-ele">
  <p>This is the target container</p>
</div>
```